# how to call a vaadin UI?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, vaadin7

OK so this might seem like a stupid question but how does a Vaadin UI work?

What I mean here is: 
How can I reach the ui from a servlet, for example (since it is not just a html page, nor a class I can instantiate)

My problem is this:
I followed [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/cHSbFrr6Q6k?t=26m11s) to make a vaadin ui and deploy it to GAE, except when I get to the webpage I reach the list of active servlets and from there I can send requests to the servlets. But nowhere can i find the UI I made (in the MyUI.java file), whis is pretty much the reason I have to use Vaadin.

I am probably missing something fundamental as this is the first web application I ever made, but i've been searching for 2 days and have yet to find an answer.

Comment: Could you please explain what your mean by finding your UI? I might be able to help.

Comment: I was trying to display the UI I built in the MyUI class but did not know what URL to type (it was actually the root URL), but the problem solved itself: simply deleting the Index.html page which popped instead of the UI.

Comment: Good to hear that you solved your problem :)

Comment: Do I delete my question or should I leave it if people have the same issue?

Comment: You can answer your own question,it's totally fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue I had actually was that the default eclipse project had an index.html page, which was displayed instead of the UI upon loading the application.

Deleting the Index.html page does the trick.
That or editing the web.xml page so that the UI is not at the root url, to avoid a conflict.